# Clone jQuery not work listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. I've a function `dropcopy()` that calls on a div for drag&drop.

```
function dropcopy(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  elencoOggetti = new Array();
  var copyimg = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  //copyimg.id = data;       
  ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);

}
```

This function copy the object but not work the listener on clone. The listener is this

```
$("#filtro").click(function() {
  alert('ciao');
});
```

Why isn't it working? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't clone an element without changing its `id`. IDs must be unique.

Event listeners are binded to the first element when created. Clones doesn't have the listeners binded. You can bind it again, or bind the listeners to a parent object instead of the objects themselves. You can do that like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#filtro', function(){
    alert('ciao');
});
```

This means the listener is attached to the body instead of the element itself, and it'll be fired only if the event was fired by #filtro.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you are binding the element, when it is not existing, so add the guard:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#filtro").click(function(){
        alert('ciao');
    });
}
```

If you wanna bind it after cloning, you can rerun this function above:

```
function resetUI(){

   $("#filtro").click(function(){
   alert('ciao');
    });
 }
```

Or overwrite the DOM, look on the docs of jquery if you wanna bind that to every name on update.